# ESP01 flashing error

Tags: esp8266

I am trying to program an ESP8266-01 WiFi module using an Arduino Uno as a USB to TTL programmer.
I have removed the ATmega and grounded the RESET pin (quite useless without the uC though).
Then, using esptool.py I tried to upload a Bare minimum sketch with the Arduino IDE and later using the following:

```
python esptool.py -b 57600 -p /dev/cu.usbport write_flash 0x000000 "nodemcu.bin"
```

However, both ways give me the same output:

```
A fatal error occurred: Failed to connect to ESP8266: Invalid head of packet ('\x08')
```

I have tried sending AT commands to the ESP01 like "AT" or "AT+GMR" and everything works fine, but I cannot upload any sketch because of that error.

I also followed esp8266 [official forum](http://www.esp8266.com/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=442&start=16) advice to edit the Python script according to the following, but without success.

```
Line 43 ESP RAM BLOCK = 0x1800 //change this to 180
Line 44 ESP RAM BLOCK = 0x400 //change this to 40
```

The level conversion from 5v TTL to 3.3v is done through simple resistor node (2k and 1k), while RST is kept at Vcc through 10k pull-up resistor and a push button to ground it.

[image: Wiring]

Comment: Are you sure 57600 is the correct baud rate? Wasn't it 115200?

Comment: I have tried both, nothing changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your wiring sounds wrong.

Tie CHPD to Vcc (3.3v) to enable the device.

Tie GPIO0 to ground as you power up, to put it into programming mode.

RST can be left floating, or PULL (not tie!) up to Vcc through a resistor, say 10k.

That diode level shifter arrangement is unusual. A potential divider on the ESP's RxD is all you need - say 1k and 2k.

Comment: I tried and I still get the same error

Comment: Could you post a circuit diagram of what you tried, please?

Comment: Sure, check it out now

Comment: According to your new schematic, RST is tied to GND. Is that just a mistake in the drawing?

Comment: Yes it was a mistake, RST goes to Vcc through a 10k resistor as you suggested and to GND via push button

Answer (score 0):

An addition to Mark's answer, from [Uploading sketch to ESP8266](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/17571/uploading-sketch-to-esp8266)

> Before download, pull both GPIO0 and RST to ground. Release the pull
>   down on RST, but keep GPIO0 low. When the IDE has finished uploading,
>   release GPIO0 from low.